# Calculator logical errors

Tags: java, calculator

I am working on a simple calculator with java and i have run into some errors.

In my code I wrote it so that when the multiplication button is clicked it multiplies the first two entered numbers, but when the button is clicked nothing happens.

Also for some reason when the subtract button is clicked, it adds the second number that has been inputted.

For some reason the debugger isn't much help too.

Is anyone seeing something that im not?

```
int num1;
int num2;
int ans;

boolean kms = false;
boolean multiplication = false;
boolean division = false;
boolean subtract = false;
boolean addition = false;

public App() {

    times.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            txt.setText("X");
            kms = true;
            multiplication = true;

        }
    });
    div.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            txt.setText("/");
            kms = true;
            division = true;
        }
    });
    min.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            txt.setText("-");
            kms = true;
            subtract = true;
        }
    });
    plus.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            txt.setText("+");
            kms = true;
            addition = true;
        }
    });

    clear.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            ans = 0;
            num1 = 0;
            num2 = 0;
            txt .setText("");
        }
    });

    if(kms == true){

        //Second number being inputted
        num1 = Integer.parseInt(txt.getText());
        txt.setText("");

        one.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                txt.setText("1");
                num2 = num2 + 1;

            }
        });
        two.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                txt.setText("2");
                num2 = num2 + 2;
            }
        });
        three.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                txt.setText("3");
                num2 = num2 + 3;
            }
        });
        four.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                txt.setText("4");
                num2 = num2 + 4;
            }
        });
        five.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                txt.setText("5");
                num2 = num2 + 5;
            }
        });
        six.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                txt.setText("6");
                num2 = num2 + 6;
            }
        });
        seven.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                txt.setText("7");
                num2 = num2 + 7;
            }
        });
        eight.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                txt.setText("8");
                num2 = num2 + 8;
            }
        });
        nine.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                txt.setText("9");
                num2 = num2 + 9;
            }
        });
        zero.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                txt.setText("0");
                num2 = num2 + 0;
            }
        });

    }else if(kms == false){
        //First number being inputted
        one.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                txt.setText("1");
                num1 = num1 + 1;
            }
        });
        two.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                txt.setText("2");
                num1 = num1 + 2;
            }
        });
        three.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                txt.setText("3");
                num1 = num1 + 3;
            }
        });
        four.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                txt.setText("4");
                num1 = num1 + 4;
            }
        });
        five.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                txt.setText("5");
                num1 = num1 + 5;
            }
        });
        six.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                txt.setText("6");
                num1 = num1 + 6;
            }
        });
        seven.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                txt.setText("7");
                num1 = num1 + 7;
            }
        });
        eight.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                txt.setText("8");
                num1 = num1 + 8;
            }
        });
        nine.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                txt.setText("9");
                num1 = num1 + 9;
            }
        });
        zero.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                txt.setText("0");
                num1 = num1 + 0;
            }
        });


        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(multiplication == true){
                    ans = num1 * num2;
                    txt.setText("Your answer is " + ans);
                    ans = 0;
                    num1 = 0;
                    num2 = 0;
                }else if(division == true){
                    ans = num1 / num2;
                    txt.setText("Your answer is " + ans);
                    ans = 0;
                    num1 = 0;
                    num2 = 0;
                }else if(subtract == true){
                    ans = num1 - num2;
                    txt.setText("Your answer is " + ans);
                    ans = 0;
                    num1 = 0;
                    num2 = 0;
                }else if(addition == true){
                    ans = num1 + num2;
                    txt.setText("Your answer is " + ans);
                    ans = 0;
                    num1 = 0;
                    num2 = 0;
                }
            }
        });

    }
}



public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Calculator");
    frame.setBackground(Color.white);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setContentPane(new App().main);
    frame.pack();
}
}
```

Comment: Now is a good time to learn how to use a debugger.  Really

Comment: You think i havent tried?

Comment: @Swize it seems like you have asked the same question twice. I will address the issue below to be help of others who would refer this post in future.

Answer (score 0):

According to what you have done in the above code if you enter integers with only one digit it would work perfectly.

Ex: add 5 then `num1=5` and press `+` button then `kms` is `true`, then enter 6 and `num2=6` now if you press the `result` the result will be 11.

But if you try to enter another digit before the result, This entered digit will be added to `num2` like `num2 = num2 + newAddedDigit` instead of **concatenating** to `num2`

so in order to get the real functionality of a calculator try to **concatenate** on number buttons pressed for `num1` and `num2`

the same issue have been addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50275620/java-calculator-errors) also. Hope this helps somehow.

cheers happy coding